# Getting data from one sheet to another on the user input

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook, and in that workbook I have a number of sheets.
One is called `main` and the other sheet `data` which holds all the information.
 The `data` sheet has people's name and assigned numbers in the same cell.

e.g.: A2 would have: `123 Chris Smith`

What I am trying to achieve is for a user to start typing the number anywhere in the main sheet that it scans the data sheet and completes the rest of the data.
So a user would type 123 and the macro would then fill out the rest 123 Chris Smith.

Comment: It is doable, by searching whenever the WorkSheet_Change event is procced. However, I suspect the performance on this might be quite poor...

Comment: Have you thought about using AuUtoComplete Data validation?  [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/autocomplete-validation.htm) is a link that may help.  Not sure if it is what you want, because it allows a single cell to be "completed", and doesn't allow other values to be put in other cells, but you could do that with Lookup functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned you can use the `Worksheet_Change()` Event. To Show you how it works, put this code in the `main` sheet in the editor. Now type any number that matches your data list and click out of the cell, it will be now completed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim val As Variant: val = Target.Value

Set sht = Worksheets("Data")

If Not IsError(val) And Not IsArray(val) Then
    If val <> "" Then
        Set rng = sht.Range("A:A").Find(val & "*", LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Value = rng.Value
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry to be a pain when I delete the cell I have entered the number in it comes up with the following error "run-time error 13: Type Mismatch" it highlight this part of the code  `Dim val As String: **val = Target.Value**`

Comment: Try this Version :)

Comment: It is still throwing up the same error but only when I use delete instead of backspace. Thank you for helping.

Comment: I found out what was causing the error , it was due to the cells where I would input the number was merged, unmerging the cells stops the error happening

Comment: I was now able to recreate the error. Thank you for finding it out. The type mismatch happend because it returnen an array, not it should work fine and also prevents of copy and pasting multiple data at once. It could be edited to process arrays though.

Comment: Thank you UGP, you have really helped me today.

Comment: Sorry last question I promise, if I wanted to exclude a cell from the above macro, how would i do it eg, if I wanted  R1 to have any number entered in it and not to add the relevant data:

Comment: [This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213612/how-to-run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel) is an example that should help you. You can set a range where the code should do something. If you have a range thats not contingous, use [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff834621.aspx).

Comment: Hello I have managed to get everything working just fine but I do have an issue with the number 0. If I have  a person numbered _0123 Smith Vehicle ab777 4ed_ and  another person numbered _672 Jones Vehicle eu123 lpk_ If type in 0123  I would expect the person called smith to show up , but it doesn't it brings the person Jones shows up due to 123 being in the vehicle. Is their a way for this not to happen?

Comment: You can say `Set rng = sht.Range("A:A").Find(val & "*", LookAt:=xlWhole)` and it will match the whole string so your input `0123` would only match a string starting with `0123 *`.  But you will need to have the cells in a text format, otherwise it will cut out the `0` and it wont match.

Comment: When I add that it stops the macro from working. Sorry I know you gave spent more than enough time helping me, I do appreciate it.

Comment: It probably cant match because of some formating, have you formated the cell where you type in as text and not default?

Comment: Thankyou it was a formatting issue, I will stop bothering you.